# Qubes networking for custom template

Tags: networking, qubes

I installed Qubes a few days ago to try it, and so far it was okay, with the built-in templates and stuff the current version (4.0) is more or less stable and usable.

My problems began when I decided to setup a custom templateVM (kali) to experience the process and see how it works. 
I can tell that the qvm creation and the os install was smooth except one thing. 
I couldn't get networking on my new template. I've did my research on the topic and went through [this](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/hvm/) article multiple times, but still I'm definitely missing something.

I checked the IP and a gateway address in Qube Manager, and configured the template manually to use those addresses, however still no Internet. I'm able to ping the gateway, but that is all I can do from that VM.

I event configured it to connect directly to net-vm, thought bypassing firewall might solve it, but didn't helped.

Anyone could kick me to the right direction what to look for or what to double check?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I had a similar problem with fedora-28-minimal, as I described below I managed to make it work, but only temporarily. But with the standard template fedora-28 the network was configured automatically after I setup the networking in Qubes Setting.

Update: This below worked until I rebooted the VM. Now I get "Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway" when adding the route.

I think I had a similar problem but for me setting up the networking manually worked:

`ip addr add x.x.x.x/24 dev eth0 
ip route add default via y.y.y.y dev eth0`

where x.x.x.x is the qube IP address and y.y.y.y is the Gateway address taken from the qube settings in Qube Manager (section Networking)

Then I also had to edit the /etc/resolve.conf file and put there the content I found in a different AppVM.

And then I could ping public servers.